# Are there any alternatives to access the results of a query that will only produce one row?

Tags: php, codeigniter, resultset

I query a table on it's primary index, and it will produce only one row result.

```
$query= $this->db->query('SELECT Name FROM people WHERE PersonID = 1');
```

To now access that 'Name', it seems to me that I have to always iterate through the result set.

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)  {
    echo $row->Name;
}
```

Does one always have to iterate through the resultset? I understand there maybe good reasons for it, but is it absolutely required in all situations? Is there no way to just go straight to something like

```
echo $query->result()->Name     //pseudo code - won't actually work
```

(This is PHP / CodeIgniter)

Comment: I am not familiar with codeingiter but PDO does support a [fetchall](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) which simply returns the entire array (handy if you know there will be one row) at once. If you can use this approach, I am happy to flesh this out into a proper answer.

Comment: PDO? I am interested to hear more, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query->first_row()->Name
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: As they say... Palm. Face. Slap.

Answer (score 0):

try `$this->db->query('...')->fetchObject()->Name` as `fetch` returns array

UPDATE: code works for PDO, for codeigniter can use

`$this->db->query('...')->result()->Name`

Comment: I'm getting an error that "Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_result::fetchObject() in ...." which I'm guessing is because CodeIgniter has it's own database class, and you're suggesting a PHP PDO class? (Does that make sense?)

Comment: @Maxcott yes, in codeigniter you can use `_fetch_object` or just result - it returns object too

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at these 2 functions

```
function _getColumn($table, $column, $where = array()) {

        $this->db->select($column);
        $q = $this->db->get_where($table, $where);
        return ($q->num_rows() > 0) ? $q->result()[0]->$column : FALSE;

}

//after calling this function your result is as follows

var_dump($this->model_name->_getColumn('people', 'name', array('personID' => '1')));
//output
//string(6) "Maxcot" //or BOOLEAN(FALSE)
//also please note that it can not handle as "$column" parameter this input = "id, name"
```

second function is to get more columns

```
function _getColumns($table, $column, $where = array()) {
        $this->db->select($column);
        $this->db->where($where);
        $q = $this->db->get($table);
        return ($q->num_rows() > 0) ? $q->result()[0] : FALSE;
}

//after calling function like this
$person_info = $this->model_name->_getColumn('people', 'name, address, phone', array('personID' => '1'));

//you can access table columns like this (also check if $person_info is not FALSE)
$person_info->name;// ->address, ->phone
```